# How does the Microsoft outlook 2003 pst backup tool work?

Tags: backup, microsoft-outlook-2003

First of all I'm sorry If I'm asking this question in the wrong place.

I'm curious about how the backup tool on outlook 2003 works. Does this tool automatically copies the whole pst file or checks the pst file for changes and only add the changes to the backup pst.

I'm asking this because I want to learn if this tool tries to copy a 2GB(or larger) sized pst file as a whole or just make changes on it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the Personal Folder Backup tool in Outlook 2003/2007 and it copies the entire PST file to the location you specify. I used to keep 2 or 3 PST backups on my backup drive at a time.

Last time I checked the tool wasn't available for Outlook 2010 so I just copy the PST manually once a day now.

Comment: You can export PSTs in Outlook 2010 through the import/export wizard...

Comment: Here's a support thread that outlines a registry hack on how to get it working in Outlook 2010: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookcontact/thread/bb2997ba-2ce0-4b72-9ab1-3f758efcbe79

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at www.datamills.com, their PST2PST backup is making miracles to the scattered PST files in the organization.